# Improper integral of $e^{tx} \cdot \frac{ba}{Γ(x)} \cdot x^{a-1} \cdot e^{-bx} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I have this massive integral that I would just put into an integral calculator normally (not trying to do this out manually because of the complexity), but the existence of the gamma function within the integrand makes it impossible for me to enter on the integral calculator sites I know. This is the integral:

$$\int_0^∞ e^{tx} \cdot \frac{ba}{Γ(x)} \cdot x^{a-1} \cdot e^{-bx} dx$$

$t$, $a$, and $b$ are constants.

> What is the solution to this integral?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). In addition, what is your motivation for this integral?

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: It should be working now.

Comment: My motivation for solving this is because it corresponds to the expectation of a probability distribution I am interested in figuring out more explicitly rather than just this integral.

Comment: Are you able to show me how to solve this?

Comment: Very little hope to get a closed form resul  (even using special functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the reflection formula we [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Integral_representations) $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)} = \frac{1}{-2i\pi} \int_C (-z )^{-x} e^{-z}dz$$ So you want $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a-1} e^{-bx}}{\Gamma(x)}dx=\frac{1}{-2i\pi}\int_C  e^{-z}\int_0^\infty (-z)^{-x} x^{a-1} e^{-bx}dx  dz \\= \frac{\Gamma(a)}{-2i\pi}\int_C e^{-z} (b+\log(-z))^{-a} dz $$ For $a,b$ real it is  $$= \frac{\Gamma(a)}{-\pi}\Im(\int_0^\infty e^{-y} (b+\log 
 y+i\pi)^{-a} dy)$$